# Data between close double quote (") and field separator

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I get the following error when loading a TSV file to a Big Query table.

```
 Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.
```

1) I tried escaping double quote character by using a backslash. This approach does load the data without error, but backslash used for escaping is present in the final table.

[image]

2) I also tried using a double-quote character for escaping. It works when the double-quote is not the first character in the field. And in this approach too, a double-quote used for escaping is present in the output.

[image]

3) I tried putting a field that has a double-quote character inside the double quotes and using double quote to escape double quote. So "A" Hat becomes """A"" Hat". This worked but again preserved double double-quotes.

[image]

My example tsv file is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1d44f94jdagmy2/examples.tsv?dl=0

So what is the way to escape double quotes in TSV so that they do not appear in the final table?

Comment: the double quotes should work, do you have sample file I can use to test it?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I have edited the question with the link to the example file.